# Issue with npx expo start react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hello all I have  a problem when I launch npx expo start, this is the result of the command :
**Starting project at C:\Users\agres\Desktop\Coding\ReactNative\AwesomeProject
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cacheStores')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cacheStores')
at C:\Users\agres\Desktop\Coding\ReactNative\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro-config\src\loadConfig.js:90:20
at Array.reduce ()
at mergeConfig (C:\Users\agres\Desktop\Coding\ReactNative\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro-config\src\loadConfig.js:85:18)
at loadMetroConfigFromDisk (C:\Users\agres\Desktop\Coding\ReactNative\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro-config\src\loadConfig.js:176:10)
at async loadConfig (C:\Users\agres\Desktop\Coding\ReactNative\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro-config\src\loadConfig.js:255:25)
at async Object.loadAsync (C:\Users\agres\Desktop\Coding\ReactNative\AwesomeProject\node_modules@expo\metro-config\build\ExpoMetroConfig.js:31                                                               6:10)
at async loadMetroConfigAsync (C:\Users\agres\Desktop\Coding\ReactNative\AwesomeProject\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\start\server\metro\ins                                                               tantiateMetro.js:47:18)
at async Object.instantiateMetroAsync (C:\Users\agres\Desktop\Coding\ReactNative\AwesomeProject\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\start\server\m                                                               etro\instantiateMetro.js:75:57)
at async MetroBundlerDevServer.startImplementationAsync (C:\Users\agres\Desktop\Coding\ReactNative\AwesomeProject\node_modules@expo\cli\build\                                                               src\start\server\metro\MetroBundlerDevServer.js:233:66)
at async MetroBundlerDevServer.startAsync (C:\Users\agres\Desktop\Coding\ReactNative\AwesomeProject\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\start\serv                                                               er\BundlerDevServer.js:88:24)
at async DevServerManager.startAsync (C:\Users\agres\Desktop\Coding\ReactNative\AwesomeProject\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\start\server\De                                                               vServerManager.js:162:13)
at async startAsync (C:\Users\agres\Desktop\Coding\ReactNative\AwesomeProject\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\start\startAsync.js:125:5)**

Do you know what's the problem here ?

npx expo start but i have an error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.